# How do CORS requests work from within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, cors

Using javascript, we can make a cross origin request using XMLHttpRequest.

A cross origin request requires the requested host to give a response only to preapproved hosts.

When making a XHR request from within an iframe (our content from host A makes a request to site C, but is loaded into an iframe on site B). Which host/origin(s) must be allowed on site C for the request to go through?

Comment: It should still be A. Doesn't it work for some reason for you?

Comment: That makes sense. I was thinking a page can only use one origin. But I guess iframes preserve origin so when you load the iframe, that iframe can make requests based on the origin it was loaded from?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I haven't tried it yet, I wanted to get some background before I tried every combination hoping one would work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're doing in your question, but the rule is fairly simple: The origin of the request is based on the window the code is running in. So if that code is running in the iframe's window, the origin is the iframe's origin, not the origin of the page containing the iframe.

So if you have:

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| [B] Page from http://example1.com |         |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| Content                                     |
| ...                                         |
| ...                                         |
| +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
| | [A] http://example2.com                 | |
| +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
| | Content                                 | |
| | ...                                     | |
| | ...                                     | |
| +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

...and the code making the request is in the iframe (A), the origin of the request is `http://example2.com`.